# carriage return in webview using string.xml

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using a webView,and the code I am writting is located into string.xml:

```
String contact = "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"> " + "\n" +
        "<body style=\"font-family:Arial;text-align:center;\">" + "\n"  
        context.getString(R.string.contact_text) + "\n"+
        "</body>" + "\n" +
        "</html>";
    webContact.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, contact, "text/html","utf-8", null);
```

The problem is that in R.string.contact_text I have carriage return, but they are not written.

I tried with

```
      \n
      <br>
      <br></br>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: try with <p> tag...is it working ?

Answer (score 0):

Please surround you message with **< pre>** tag
It preserves both spaces and line breaks.

< pre>
Your message goes here
< /pre>